# C# SocketException: Address already in use

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, exception, network-programming

I am trying to establish a connection through Sockets to send data (for testing purposes to the local IP address, meaning the computer is sending data to "itself").

Previously, everything worked perfectly fine for weeks throughout the development, meaning the connection could be established, the data could be sent and received and the connection could finally be closed, but a few days later, also after restarting my router, I am getting a `SocketException` (98) when trying to bind the "listener" Socket to an end point with `IPAddress.Any` (0.0.0.0) with the message: `Address already in use.`

The source code has not changed in between. The Socket is supposed to accept any connection from any IP-Address, as it is the "listener" Socket for receiving data.
I am using .NET 6.0.301.

This is a simplified version of the relevant source code:

```cs
// In the constructor of the base-class:
IpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port); // Random unused port that also hasn't changed
// ...

// Gets called in the constructor of the derived class
private async Task ReceiveDataAsync()
{
    using Socket listener = new(IpEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    try
    {
        listener.Bind(IpEndPoint); // Fails here!!!
        listener.Listen(100);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }

    while(true)
    {
        using Socket handler = await listener.AcceptAsync();
        // Receive data...
    }
}
```

This method is **called only once** and the exception throws at the very first cycle of the loop. It is called, of course, long before the attempt to establish a connection to this IP.
It might also be important noting that I didn't close the connection after receiving the data with the `Shutdown`, `DisconnectAsync` and `Close` methods, but this has always been done on the client side after the data had been sent.

And here is the exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (98): Address already in use
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at ....ReceiveDataAsync() ...
```

**EDIT:**
This is the output of `netstat -ntpl | grep 0.0.0.0` while my IDE, JetBrains Rider is running with the relevant project being opened (but it isn't executing):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31415           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
10064/dotnet        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42103         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
9560/Rider.Backend  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33747         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
9560/Rider.Backend  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
-                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
-
```

Killing the process, which occupies the port, doesn't have much of an effect, as a new process gets created when I launch the application again.

Comment: Print the address selected at IPEndpoint variable. Then see on your dev server if that IP already exists. Using `netstat -ntpl | grep <selected-ip>` command

Comment: 1) What is `Port`? Specifically, is it in the registered port range or ephemeral port range? 2) Use [`TcpView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) to determine what app already has that port open. 3) It's not normal to recreate a listening socket; it's normal to have one listening socket that can do multiple Accepts.

Comment: @Shades88 As already mentioned, it is 0.0.0.0 (IPAddress.Any). While my IDE, JetBrains Rider, is running with the relevant project being opened (but it isn't executing), there are several entries printed in the console. I edited the post with the relevant details.

Comment: @StephenCleary 1) `Port` is indeed within the demanded port range (0 - 65535), otherwise it would throw an exception upon creating the `IPEndPoint` instance. It is 31415. I tried other ports, without a positive effect. 2) I'm afraid I can't use this on Linux. 3) Yes, what you see there is a result of my attempts to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: As you should be able to see from the netstat, the port is currently in use by a dotnet process. Do you have an orphaned process running? Maybe kill the process and try again?

Comment: @ricardkelly I'm not aware of any process and I don't see a reason why there would be an orphaned process running if I'm doing exactly the same as a few days ago to run this application (in Debug mode) and the device, it is running on, was freshly started.

And changing the port doesn't have any positive effect.

Comment: @ricardkelly Killing the process doesn't do much, except that another one gets created when I run the application again. I'm also trying to get behind the cause of this, as I don't want to kill processes each time I run the application, which apparently doesn't work anyway. But thank you for your input, it's very much appreciated!

Comment: @User: `TcpView` is a Windows application. If you're opening multiple listening ports, then you'll need to close the old ones.

Comment: @StephenCleary You mean, each time I create a new Socket on this port as a listening port, I need to disconnect and close the old one, even if it gets disposed. Well, sure, but it seems like I can't get rid of those that have been created before.

Answer (score 2):

A `Bind` on a fixed endpoint inside a `while (true)` is hugely suspicious. You only need to bind once - a single listener socket can accept any number of client connections. Refactor the code so you only bind and listen once, and then just have the accept in the `while` loop.

If it can't bind even the first time, then that suggests a rogue process is holding the port, or *possibly* a firewall problem. But my money would be on a rogue process. If you can't find it, try rebooting - if that fixes it: it was a rogue process (probably your own program started from a debugger, or similar).

Comment: Hello , thank you very much for your answer. I've rebooted many times, killed processes that seemingly occupy the port, but all that doesn't seem to free this port.

Comment: @User then check the firewall/permissions?

Comment: Somehow, and I really don't know how, it suddenly started working. Without any changes to the code, to the firewall or permissions. I really can't get behind the reason for this, but it worked for the last two days.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'm trying to find a way to check bindability. The debugger doesn't kill the rogue process so I'm trying to figure out a way to check for and fix the problem at run-time. Is this just something that is going to plague us when we debug or is there a way to work around it?